# What software development methodology was used to develop Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

Do you use agile or waterfall? What documentation is kept?

Comment: Note that the answer to this question has *drastically* changed since the answers to this question were posted. You can find current information at [Which tools and technologies are used to build the Stack Exchange Network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-are-used-to-build-the-stack-exchange-network)

Answer (score 13):

[image]
<sub>(source: [stackoverflow.com](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/bug-bash-stackoverflow-development-process.png))</sub>

And if you’re wondering what our software engineering process looks like from here on the inside, [this video reveals all](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=08xQLGWTSag).

Comment: The linked video is not available any more, just checked :-) I'm located in germany, but it doesn't look like a geolocation block.

Answer (score 8):

Stack Overflow was built by a **small team** of **very experienced** (and committed) developers; therefore it is likely that no formal development methodology was needed.

From the outside it looks like they used:

> Keep saying No to every “feature
>   request”, until they can no longer
>   think of a reason to say No.

Comment: if everyone works like 'that', methdology will soon be in the books only.